# Trying to figure out the classic Knapsack recurrence

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I am reading about the `Knapsack Problem` (unbounded) which is, as I understand a classic in DP.
Although I think I understand the solution as I read it, I am not clear how I can translate it to actual code.
For example in the following recurrence "formula":

`M(j) = MAX {M(j-1), MAX i = 1 to n (M(j - Si) + Vi) }   for j >=1`

I am not sure how I can translate this to code, since it is not clear to me if the inner `MAX` should be there or it should just be instead:
`M(j) = MAX {M(j-1), M(j - Si) + Vi }   for j >=1`

Any help to figure out the formula and to code it?

Comment: Honestly, I don't care about downvotes as long as you write a reason....

Comment: you know what, same thing for my some of my posts. downvoting without no reason mentioned.

Comment: Maybe better for http://cstheory.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @WaleedKhan:Was not aware of that SE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can code it like this:

```
for w = 0 to W   //W is the maximum capacity
V[0,w] = 0
for i = 1 to n
V[i,0] = 0
for i = 1 to n
for w = 0 to W
    if wi <= w // item i can be part of the solution
        if  bi + V[i-1,w-wi] > V[i-1,w]
            V[i,w] = bi + V[i-1,w- wi]
        else
            V[i,w] = V[i-1,w]
    else V[i,w] = V[i-1,w]  // wi > w
```

[image]

this means the following:

It means, that the best subset of Sk that has total weight w is:

1) the best subset of Sk-1 that has total weight > w,    or

2) the best subset of Sk-1 that has total weight > w-wk plus the item k

The best subset of Sk that has the total weight > w, either contains item k or not.

**First case**: wk>w. Item k can’t be part of the solution, since if it was, the total weight would be > w, which is unacceptable.

**Second case**: wk <= w. Then the item k can be in the solution, and we choose the case with greater value.

Comment: This does not seem the same as the formula in OP. Is the formula wrong?

Comment: no, I',m editing my post to add the recursive formula for you

Comment: I assume that `w` is the size of the knapsack.Still this is different than my formula right?

Comment: yes, your formula is not wrong, but it's not clear at all. and yes those differ from each others. But the one I posted is 100% tested.

Comment: But this is my question.Why is it not wrong.Yours takes the max of 2 cases. While the inner max in my formula seems wrong.So if theoritically is not wrong, could you please explain it to me?

Comment: and yours is taking the max of two cases too. in the M(j - Si) and M(j-1), or at least this is what I understood from your formula.

Comment: what exactly are you missing here??

Comment: I am talking about the **inner** MAX. I.e. this part:`MAX i = 1 to n (M(j - Si) + Vi)`

Comment: ah!!!. I see, no mine is taking the max just one time. just when wk>w.
I see that you didn't get my formula exactly. Should I edit with more explanation??

Comment: I got your formula, but your editions are all wrong and confusing.For example you say:`First case: wk>w` and `Second case: wk > w` which is obviously wrong.Please make the answer clearer fixing typos etc and I will mark it as accepted!

Comment: sorry. I fixed the cases state. just second case should be less or equal. Thank you for pointing that up.

Comment: `It means, that the best subset of Sk that has total weight w is:` But what is `Sk`? It is not part of the formula or your code

Comment: Sk = {items labeled 1, 2, .. k} in a knapsack of size w

Comment: I don't see how your formula takes into account of the case of the max selection to be a knapsack of less capacity than `w`.So it is different than the one in my OP.

Comment: yes, sure it's different. but what I said is theoretically, I think that yours is not wrong. but in DP this is how to use knapsack ( like in mine ).

Comment: I will accept this.There is something that still confuses me but I think I will open another thread for this

Comment: yes, sure, thanks, and if there's a way to tag me please do :)

Comment: The other thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137267/can-not-understand-knapsack-solutions