# Can not understand knapsack solutions

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, recursion, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

In wikipedia the algorithm for Knapsack is as follows:

```
for i from 1 to n do  
  for j from 0 to W do  
    if j >= w[i] then  
      T[i, j] := max(T[i-1, j], T[i-1, j-w[i]] + v[i]) [18]  
    else  
      T[i, j] := T[i-1, j]  
    end if  
  end for  
end for
```

And it is the same structures on all examples I found online.
What I can not understand is how does this code take into account the fact that perhaps the max value comes from a **smaller** knapsack? E.g. if the knapsack capacity is 8 then perhaps max value comes from capacity 7 (8 - 1).
 I could not find anywhere logic to consider that perhaps the max value comes from a smaller knapsack. Is this wrong idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to figure out the classic Knapsack recurrence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103846/trying-to-figure-out-the-classic-knapsack-recurrence)

Comment: hi, can you reform your question in clearer way? Still didn't get your point here. In your previous example I can see one of two. "and my apologies for my language" either you didn't get the concept of knapsack, or it was just not clear for me. if you like I can post an answer with clarifications for knapsack and it's divisions. besides some other features.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan:Perhaps I don't get the concept as you say.If you can post clarifications that could help straighten things out, it would be great!

Answer (score 5):

The Dynamic Programming solution of knapsack is basically recursive:

```
T(i,j) = max{ T(i-1,j) ,         T(i-1,j-w[i]) + v[i] }
       //      ^                         ^
       //  ignore the element       add the element, your value is increase
       //                           by v[i] and the additional weight you can
       //                           carry is decreased by w[i]
```

(The else condition is redundant in the recursive form if you set `T(i,j) = -infinity` for each `j < 0`).

The idea is exhaustive search, you start from one element and you have two possibilities: add it, or don't.

You check both options, and chose the best of those.

Since it is done recursively - you effectively checking ALL possibilities to assign the elements to the knapsack.

Note that the solution in wikipedia is basically a bottom-up solution for the same recursive formula

Comment: But isn't the return value `T(n,total)`? Where total is the full capacity of the knapsack?

Comment: @Cratylus: Exactly, by invoking `T(n,total)` you return the best solution for the first `n` elements with a weight limit of `total`, which is exactly what you need. In the DP solution, `T[i,j]` is the value the recursive formula `T(i,j)` would have returned.

Comment: But by returning `T(n,total)` how do we know that there isn't a better solution with less capacity?I.e. `T(n, total-1)` or `T(n-1,total-1)`?This will depend on the item't values right?

Comment: @Cratylus: Of course it depends on the items, but since we are getting `max {T(n-1,total), T(n-1,total-w[n]) + v[n] }`, we check these options as well - and chose the best out of them.

Comment: This is the part I am lost.We are always getting the `max` either including `i` or not including `i` as in your answer. But what about including `i` but in smaller knapsack i.e.     
`T(i,j) = max{ T(i-1,j) , T(i-1,j-w[i]) + v[i], T(i, j - 1) }`?

Comment: @Cratylus: The idea is: If the "smaller knapsack" can be generated, then the recursive formula would have checked it already. For example, if you have 5 elements, and the "best" is (1,2,5), the recursive formula for checking `T(4,total-w[5])` will return `(1,2)` because it is the best knapsack with elements [1,2,3,4] with max weight of `total-w[5]`.

Comment: Ok.`T(4, total-w[5])` is the part `T(i-1,j-w[i])` right? What about `T(5, total-w[5])` i.e. there is a smaller knapsack that gives `(1,2,5)` that can fit in a smaller capacity?Am I wrong here?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22138/discussion-between-amit-and-cratylus)

Answer (score 4):

As I see, you have misunderstood the concept of knapsack. which I will describe here in details till we reach the code part.

First, there are two versions of the problem:

1. **0-1 knapsack problem**: here, the Items are indivisible, you either take an item or not. and can be solved with *dynamic programming*. `//and this one is the one yo are facing problems with`
2. **Fractional knapsack problem**: don't care about this one now.

For the first *problem* you can understand it as the following:

Given a knapsack with maximum capacity **W**, and a set **S** consisting of **n** items
Each item **i** has some weight **wi** and benefit value **bi**  (all **wi**  and **W** are integer values).

> SO, How to pack the knapsack to achieve maximum total value of packed
>   items?

and in mathematical mouth:

[image]

and to solve this problem using *Dynamic Programming* We set up a table `V[0..k, 0..W]` with one row for each available item, and one column for each weight from **0** to **W**.
We need to carefully identify the *sub-problems*,

The *sub-problem* then will be to compute `V[k,w]`, i.e., to find an optimal solution for 
`Sk= {items labeled 1, 2, .. k}` in a knapsack of size **w** (maximum value achievable given capacity **w** and items **1,…, k**)

So, we found this formula to solve our problem:
[image]

This algorithm only finds the **max possible** value that can be carried in the knapsack
i.e., the value in V[n,W]
To know the items that make this maximum value, this will be another topic.

I really hope that this answer will help you. I have an pp presentation that walks with you to fill the table and to show you the algorithm step by step. But I don't know how can I upload it to stackoverflow. let me know if any help needed.

Comment: But isn't there also another version?The **unbounded** knapsack?This is what I am studying.What is the difference with the `0/1` that you mention?

Comment: **0-1 knapsack problem**: which restricts the number xi of copies of each kind of item to zero or one. 

**unbounded knapsack problem (UKP)**: places no upper bound on the number of copies of each kind of item and can be formulated as above except for that the only restriction on  is that it is a non-negative integer. If the example with the colored bricks above is viewed as an unbounded knapsack problem, then the solution is to take three yellow boxes and three grey boxes.

taken from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan Hard Knapsacks and 0-1 Knapsacks problem is the same or lies in other category..?