# Knapsack algorithm variation

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I've got a following problem:

There is a set of items, every item has 2 different positive values A and B.

The knapsack has two values: totalA and totalB. which are the maximum sums of values A and B of chosen items.

I have to find out, what the maximum items count the knapsack can hold is.

**Example:**

**Input:**

totalA: 10, totalB: 15

item1 A:3, B: 4

item2 A:7, B: 2

item3 A:1, B: 9

item4 A:2, B: 1

item5 A:4, B: 6

**Output:**

3(items: 2, 3, 4)

How should I use dynamic programming in order to solve this task?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103846/trying-to-figure-out-the-classic-knapsack-recurrence/14103876#14103876
or
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137267/can-not-understand-knapsack-solutions/14142580#14142580

Comment: The posts you linked to contain answers to a classic knapsack problem, where every item has its weight and value. Items in my case dont have values, but they have two weights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as the "multiply-constrained knapsack problem" (MKP, occasionally rendered as d-KP). It can be solved in pseudopolynomial time just like the regular knapsack problem, but you need a two-dimensional table instead of one.

Answer (score 1):

Define m[i,wa,wb] to be the maximum value (count of items here), that can be attained with  sum of `a`s being less than or equal to `wa` and sum of `b`s being less than or equal to `wb`, using items up to `i`.

```
m[i,wa,wb] = m[i-1,wa,wb]
```

if `item[i].a > wa` or `item[i].b > wb`

or

```
m[i,wa,wb] =  max (m[i-1, wb, wb], m[i-1, wa - item[i].a, wb - item[i].b] + 1)
```

if `item[i].a <= wa` and `item[i].b <= wb`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an recurrence equation that might help you :-

```
if(Items[N].b<=Wa && Items[N].b<=Wa)
    Value(N,Wa,Wb) = max(1+Value(N-1,Wa-Items[N].a,Wb-Items[N].b),Value(N-1,Wa,Wb)) 

else Value(N,Wa,Wb) = Value(N-1,Wa,Wb)

Where Wa = Current capacity of A sack & Wb of B sack
      N = no of items considered
```

Note: You can use a hash table implementation on recursive solution which would prevent of three dimensional array.